# On switches and light bulbs

Tags: linear-algebra, puzzle

> Suppose that you have $n$ switches, numbered from $1$ to $n$, connected to $n$ light bulbs, also numbered from $1$ to $n$. They are connected in the sense that turning a switch reverses the state of all light bulbs connected to that switch. There are two tules
>
> 1. the $k^{\text{th}}$ switch is connected to the $k^{\text{th}}$ light bulb;
> 2. if the $k^{\text{th}}$ switch is connected to the $m^{\text{th}}$ light bulb, then the $m^{\text{th}}$ switch is connected to the $k^{\text{th}}$ light bulb.
>
> Suppose that all the light bulbs are off. Prove that it is possible to turn all the lights on.

I was able to see that this can be seen as linear algebra problem over $\mathbb{F}_2$:

> Consider a symmetric bilinear form $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$  on ${\mathbb{F}_2}^n$ such that, for any vector $e_k$ from the canonical basis, $\langle e_k,e_k\rangle=1$. Consider also the linear form$$\begin{array}{rccc}\alpha\colon&{\mathbb{F}_2}^n&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{F}_2\\&(x_1,\ldots,x_n)&\mapsto&\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^nx_k.\end{array}$$Prove that there is a vector $v\in{\mathbb{F}_2}^n$ such that $\alpha=\langle\cdot,v\rangle$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I like to think of this in terms of matrices and vectors. All coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_2$, of course. So we are given a symmetric matrix $A$, with all $1$ on the diagonal, and need to show that the vector $e=(1,\ldots,1)^T$ belongs to the range of $A$.

Now consider a vector $z$ in the null space of $A$, and let $I\subseteq\{1,\ldots,n\}$ be the set of indices for which $z_i=1$. Then $z^TAz$ counts the number modulo $2$ of $1$ entries among the $a_{ij}$ for which $i,j\in I$. So there must be an even number of $1$ entries. But there are an even number of off-diagonal $1$ entries among those, because of the symmetry. There is a $1$ in every diagonal entry, and it follows from $z^TAz=0$ that $I$ has an even number of elements.

We have just shown that, if $z$ is in the null space of $A$, then $e^Tz=0$. But linear algebra tells us that the range of $A$ is the orthogonal complement of the null space of $A^T=A$, so $e$ is in the range of $A$.

Comment: Curiously, this answer attracted a downvote today, nearly 16 months after I posted it.

Comment: I can only speculate. May be the downvoter thought that the use of *orthogonal complement* refers only to real inner product spaces? Your argument is ok. But if $V$ is a subspace of $\Bbb{F}_2^n$ it takes a bit of adjustment to call the space
$$ V^\perp=\{x\in\Bbb{F}_2^n\mid x^Tz=0\ \text{for all $z\in V$}\}$$ the orthogonal complement of $V$ because we no longer have the fact (familiar from inner product spaces) that the sum $V+V^\perp$ is A) direct, and B) the whole space. So one can argue that $V^\perp$ is not really a complement of $V$ as adding it to V does not complete the space.

Comment: It may depend on one's native language terminology, what they expect from a complementary space :-). I just recall needing to be careful here the first time I moved outside he realm of inner product spaces over $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Your guess may well be right. Perhaps I should have used the word “annihilator” instead, but that might confuse even more readers. In any case, I think I'll let it stand. No point in bouncing the question to the home page for this. (We can hope that anyone confused by this might have a look at the comments and will be enlightened.)